# Why doesn't PHP exec() command doesn't run?

Tags: php, command, exec

I have a very simple PHP script to try to use the exec command. The code is

```
 <?php
// outputs the username that owns the running php/httpd process
// (on a system with the "whoami" executable in the path)
echo("test<br>");
echo exec('whoami');
echo("test");
?>
```

However when I access the page, it just prints out:

```
test
test
```

It does not print the output from "whoami" command, which when run from command line displays

```
me
```

What is the problem here? I cannot work it out.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is there an executable called `whoami` present?

Answer (score 0):

> (on a system with the "whoami" executable in the path)

`PATH`, like all environment variables, is not system-wide but ultimately *per-process*.

That is, though your typical bash session may well include the path to this executable in `PATH`, the environment in which your PHP script is running (say, an Apache CGI context) does not. This may be for any reason.

Provide an absolute path to `whoami`, instead.

Comment: @Starx: Specific to one _tty_, or "terminal". A terminal can be a shell session, or a prompt on an RS232 management port, or a shell process forked off the root tty from which all your daemons are invoked. Other exampes exist.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_%28Unix%29 - for further information, ask a question on SuperUser about this basic UNIX feature and watch the downvotes roll in. :)

Comment: Environment variables are per process; they have nothing to do with terminals or teletypes.

Comment: @melpomene But all processes are attached to a tty, no? Well, except the ones you've detached from a tty. My point is that the `PATH` variable specifically is almost always set up from a shell init script and inherited by the other processes spawned, even those that go on to be detached from that same tty.